# Unable to make build due to keychain how to reset it

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, keychain, certificate

I was encountered problem with my system's keychain so i followed some tutorials and cleaned my whole keychain.
Now there is nothing in my keychain under "System" but  "System Roots" has all certificates.

Now i am unable to make any build for iPhone projects.

What to do now ?

Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you drag the certificates from system roots to system?
Otherwise just download the certificates again from the Apple Development Center?

Comment: "System Roots" has different kind of certificates which are not required in "System"

Comment: well you can certainly drag certificates around in keychain, so if you have the developer certificates in the 'system root', just drag them to the 'system'